# HTML - CSS(Header)

Tags: css, html

I started working in html and css and I have an issue. I have the header and it has some space between the browser and the header itself I hope you understand what I am saying. It is just a rectangle on a background.

```css
body{
  background-image:url(bg.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header{
  background-color:#000;
  padding: top;
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PaginaWeb</title>
    <script src="External_Java.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
     
</head>

<body>

   <header>
       <nav>
           <p>text</p>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that by default, every browser includes a default padding and margin property. So you need to reset them to zero in order to avoid these kind of issues.

By adding this declaration at the beginning of your script :

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Your'e resetting the padding and margin property of **all** element, which is what the `*` stands for.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }


body{
  background-image:url(bg.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header{
  background-color:#000;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PaginaWeb</title>
    <script src="External_Java.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
     
</head>

<body>

   <header>
       <nav>
           <p>text</p>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Comment: You should close the question then ! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style

```
body {
margin : 0;
}
```

```css
body{
  background-image:url(bg.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  background-color:#000;
  padding: top;
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PaginaWeb</title>
    <script src="External_Java.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
     
</head>

<body>

   <header>
       <nav>
           <p>text</p>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header{
  background-color:#000;
  padding: top;
  min-height: 70px;
  margin-top:0px;


}
```

try this.

Comment: Nope, I still have the space

Comment: then reduce more give minus value